# Running gunicorn with multiple HTTPS Certificates?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, gunicorn

I am running gunicorn on HTTPS by using this command:

`gunicorn --certfile=cert1.pem --keyfile=key1.pem --bind 0.0.0.0:443 app:app()`

However, I have two certificates, one for www.site.com and another one for site.com. How should I go about supporting them both on gunicorn?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to create an SSL certificate that points to multiple domains. That way, you only need to reference one certfile and one keyfile, but they will both contain information to multiple domains.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/host-multiple-domains-with-a-single-certificate/20917 something similar to this answer should help.